# link appears on a new line in compatability mode

Tags: html, ie-compatibility-mode

I have some really basic HTML code...

```
<strong>Hello, Name</strong><br />Company Name<br />Account Manager:<a href="mailto:first.last@company.com">Manager Name</a>
```

this looks absolutely fine in IE and all other browsers. but when running IE in compatability mode, the link wraps to a new line, and I can't for the life of me figure out why or how to stop it!

can anyone shed any light on this for me? please?

Comment: Have you tried `a { display: inline; }` in your CSS (if you have any)?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that actually demonstrates the issue. The code posted does not.

Comment: I recommend you to not care so much about IE, also compatibility mode you should just ignore it. New versions of IE doesn't suck much as older versions.

Comment: jukka... there is no other code, that is it! 
Red Curley... im afraid i have to support compatability mode, it's a requirement :( Ignoring the problem isn't a fix to the problem. 
sean... i have tried display:inline. but i found that this had the same result, it's really strange!